# Create ACL for VLAN

Tags: acl

I've multiple switches in LAN network environment configured with 3 VLANs, namely VLAN A, VLAN B and VLAN C. Since VLAN A is only allow to access internet without having accessibility to internal network(VLAN B & C), I would like to know on how to configure by restricting VLAN A access to internet only, while deny to VLAN B & C.

Appreciate someone can guide me through this.

Thanks.

Comment: What network equipment are you using?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you deny access from VLAN A to B & C (or to the whole internal network) and then permit everything else. You might want to permit the nodes to talk to their subnet as well (gateway, DNS, ...). The first ACL entry that fits is the one that is applied.

With VLAN A using 10.0.10.0/24 and the rest of the network within 10.0.0.0/8:

```
ip access-list extended "VLAN_A"
1000 permit ip 10.0.10.0/24 10.0.10.0/24
1010 deny ip 10.0.10.0/24 10.0.0.0/8
9999 permit ip 10.0.10.0/24 0.0.0.0/0
```

Apply that ACL to VLAN A ingress or to all interfaces using VLAN A.

Comment: Thanks for the command, shall try out and response on the outcome. Btw, may I know what is the means of "1000", "1010" and "9999" at the left of each ACL ? Thanks.

Comment: @JimmyWong, those are the line numbers you assign. You should leave enough space in the numbers to be able to add lines between two existing lines, and `9999` is meant to be then end, giving you enough room to add whatever you need before it.

Comment: Do I need to set ACL in Core switch or each of the Access Switch ?

Comment: @JimmyWong That depends on where the traffic flows and what you want to block. If inter-VLAN routing happens on the core switch only that should be enough.